# Best way to save objects in database

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, erd

**The Story:**
I’m trying to develop a big application in `PHP`. The main problem is that I have to deal with the objects and I need to apply CRUD operations. Ex: Suppose we have class diagram (Compiler):

```
Project { name:string, statements:list …}
Statement{ type:string }
IfStatement exend Statement { condition:Exp, …}
…
```

**The question (What is the best design for ERD or database)**
as I know I’ve two solutions:

1. Serialize the main object and save it in the DB
2. Make a table for each class in the class diagram and linking by foreign keys

Note: I’ve read about ORM but I think it’s similar to 1st solution

Comment: Pick an ORM that works with the db in question. Don't try and reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Serializing your objects in your database is in my opinion not a good solution.
You must be able to find and edit each object properties in your database.

It requires a simple logic structure, with relations and keys.
This way you'll be able to build a CRUD Admin Dashboard, read and edit all your data in a logical and reliable way.

MySQL Workbench is a real good starting point, it communicates with PhpMyAdmin, you can use it to build your database and create shemas.

Then if you're looking for a professional CRUD Generator I suggest this one: https://www.phpcrudgenerator.com/

[Disclaimer: I'm the author]

It can build your CRUD admin dashboard in a very simple way within a few minutes, and comes with many advanced features.

The Admin dashboard generated by the CRUD Generator is powered with Bootstrap 4, jQuery, PHP objects and TWIG templates.